# AJAX: Open content in another div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I'm working with AJAX on a website and I'm currently making some pages to load on a certain div: "pageContent". Now I have another content I want to be opened on another div: "reproductor". I want to open 'page' in 'pageContent' div and 'play' in 'reproductor' div. I don't know how to modify my script.js and load_page.php files in order to make it work. Here's what I got:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<a href="#page1">PAGE</a>
<a href="#play1">PLAY</a>
<div id ="pageContent"></div>
<div id="reproductor"></div>
```

<sub>script.js:</sub>

```
var default_content="";
$(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){
        checkURL(this.hash);
    });

    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();
    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";
function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;
        if(hash=="")
            $('#pageContent').html(default_content);
        else
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}

function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');
    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }   
    });
}
```

<sub>load_page.php:</sub>

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
    echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.html');
else 
    echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

I forgot to mention: I have my 'pages' content in a folder named 'pages' and my 'play' content in another named 'plays'.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You've just dumped a bunch of uncommented code without describing in words what you're trying to do. Let's try again. What page do you want to open in the `reproductor` div?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I want to open 'page' in 'pageContent' div and 'play' in 'reproductor' div. Edited question.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not quite sure I follow. What are `page` and `play`? Are they PHP/HTML pages?

Comment: They are html pages with just html code. For example: public_html/pages/page_1.html or public_html/plays/play_1.html

Comment: it is currently working for the "page" content to load in "pageContent" div. I dont know what to modify to make "play" content to appear in "reproductor" div. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, your have two groups of links (for pages and a play list) each one to be loaded in a different container. Here is something you can try: mainly I eliminated the global variables and put the current hash inside each containter's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/), and separated the management of the two groups of links.

In this code I supposed you have a separate `load_play.php` file. If not, then you can use the same page for both kind of links, but you'll have to merge `loadPlay` with `loadPage`, change `loadPage(newHash)` to `loadPage(newHash, linkType)` and change the ajax parameter from `'page='+newHash` to `'number='+newHash+'&type='+linkType`, and do the corresponding changes server side in your PHP page. I would recommend you to create two separate PHP files in order to manage the two types of content.

I remember you where doing something with the hash of the current page's url, you can still set it in the ajax's success, inside the `loadPage` function.

Here is a working [sfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roimergarcia/3Kxuu/) example with some console calls (open browser's console) but without the ajax call.

**UPDATE**:

I updated the code, so your can manage the dynamically added links (new content loaded via AJAX) and fixed the management of urls with hashes, which was broken because of the new code.

```html
<div id="#page">
    <a href="#page1" class="pageLink">PAGE 1</a>
    <a href="#page2" class="pageLink">PAGE 2</a>
    <a href="#play1" class="playLink">PLAY 1</a>
    <a href="#play2" class="playLink">PLAY 2</a>
    <a href="#play3" class="playLink">PLAY 3</a>
    <div id ="pageContent"></div>
    <div id="reproductor"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pageContent').data('currentPage', '');
    $('#reproductor').data('currentPlay', '');

    //This will allow it to work even on dynamically created links
    $('#page').on('click', '.pageLink', function (e){
        loadPage(this.hash);
    });

    $('#page').on('click', '.playLink', function (e){
        loadPlay(this.hash);
    });

    //And this is for managing the urls with hashes (for markers)
    var urlLocation = location.hash;
    if(urlLocation.indexOf("#page") > -1){
        $('.pageLink[href='+ urlLocation +']').trigger('click')
    }

});

function loadPage(newHash)
{
    //This is the current Page
    var curHash = $('#pageContent').data('currentPage');
    //and this is the new one
    newHash = newHash.replace('#page', '');

    if(curHash===newHash){
        //If already loaded: do nothing 
        return
    }

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+newHash,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg).data('currentPage',newHash);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }   
    });
}

function loadPlay(newHash)
{//Similar to loadPage...
    var curHash = $('#reproductor').data('currentPlay');
    newHash = newHash.replace('#play', '');

    if(curHash===newHash){return}

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_play.php",
        data: 'play='+newHash,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#reproductor').html(msg).data('currentPlay',newHash);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }   
    });
}
```

Check this and comment if this is what you need, or I got something wrong :)

Comment: I forgot: you should add a `error` to your ajax call in order to hide the loading animation (an animated gif?); also, inside the `success` you'll want to put the `$('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');` _outside_ the `if`, so in case that something go wrong the _loading_ gets hidden.

Comment: It didn't work :(. I'm working with both `load_page.php` and `load_play.php` files. I have no clue to whats the problem!

Comment: I checked your website http://www.clavederock.com.ar/, but shows a "403 Forbidden" error message. If you update your website I can check it, if not try adding a `console.log()` inside both click functions to see if at least they get triggered.

Comment: OK, look at the beginning of my answer, I added two classes to the links in order to tell apart both 'kinds' of links: `pageLink` and `playLink`. This are needed so the click event are bind to them. Just add them and your page links will be working again (didn't tested the play links).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to load content from a resource that serves HTML into an element is to use `load`:

```
$('#reproductor').load('public_html/plays/play_1.html', function(){
    //stuff to do after load goes here
});
```

You could also apply this technique to the other div you are trying to load content into.

Comment: I want the URL to change each time it loads. That's why I'm using the code posted.

Comment: You can still use a dynamic URL with this one. Just pass the url variable as the first argument to `load`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why the following is not an ideal solution. The most glaring would be security - by modifying the href attribute of the link before clicking it, the user can certainly get your server to serve up any html on your server.

**EDIT** I've removed my original answer, because I can't recommend it's usage.

---

As Asad suggested, you can also use jQuery load and pass it the relevant url using some of the code above

```
function loadPage(url)
{
    // remove the hash in url
    url=url.replace('#','');
    // extract page or play - only works for four letter words
    var contentType=url.substr(0,4);
    // extract the number
    var contentId=url.substr(4);
    if ( $contentType == "page") {
        $("#pageContent #loading").css('visibility','visible');
        $("#pageContent").load($contentType+'s/'+$contentType+'_'+$contentId+'.html');
        $("#pageContent #loading").css('visibility','hidden');
    } else if ( $contentType == "play") {
        $("#reporductor #loading").css('visibility','visible');
        $("#reproductor").load($contentType+'s/'+$contentType+'_'+$contentId+'.html');
        $("#reporductor #loading").css('visibility','hidden');
    }
}
```

Comment: Which? The first or second solution? js or php?

Comment: Which solution do you find the most apropiate?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. You say there are a number of reasons I shouldn't do this. Why? and which solution would you find more apropiate?

Comment: I think this solution doesn't work because the `function` is not running when the link is clicked